The vector is not output to the console
My problem is that after replacing almost all the zeros in the vector with natural numbers, the program stops without crashing the program or any output code. My vector is not displayed on screen after several iterations of the loop without going through the loop to the end.
This is a console that displays the output of another program. Here everything ended correctly with code 0.

This is what the program gives me. It's like it's not finished. I don't understand why it doesn't exit with some code.

I tried to use Debugger, but it doesn't catch the crash
ChatGPT could not solve my problem.
Code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
    
    int delayInSeconds = 1; // Delay in seconds
    
    int D = 20;
    int T = 14;
    int K1 = 4;
    int K2 = 8;   
    int N = 8;
    int k;
    int probability;
    int x, y;
    
    vector<vector<int>> N_N(N, vector<int>(N, 0));  // field
    
    for (int i = 0; i < D; i++) {  
        // Every day we increase the number of days lived in each bact by 1
        for (int f = 0; f < N; f++) {    for every cell of the field
            for (int l = 0; l < N; l++) {
                if (N_N[f][l] != 0)     // if there is a bacterium
                    N_N[f][l] = N_N[f][l] + 1;    // increase its number of days lived by 1
            }
        }
        //adding k bacteria
        k = rand() % (K2 - K1) + K1;   
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {  // for every k
            bool added = false;

            do {   // iterate over coordinates until all bacteria can be inserted
                x = rand() % N;
                y = rand() % N;

                if (N_N[x][y] == 0) {
                    N_N[x][y] = 1;
                    added = true;
                }
            } while (!added);
        }
        //simulation of bacterial death
        for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) {     //for every cell of the field
            for (int b = 0; b < N; b++) {
                if (N_N[a][b] >= T / 2) {   // if the life of the bacterium is greater than T:2
                    probability = rand() % 100;  // probability
                    if (probability <= 2)  // if probability < 2%
                        N_N[a][b] = 0;  // the bacterium dies and the cell is released
                }
            }
        }
        // simulation of bacterial reproduction
        if (i > 0) {  // "next and every day"
            for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {  
                for (int d = 0; d < N; d++) {  
                    if (N_N[c][d] <= T) {   // "after T days after appearance, the bacterium stops reproducing"
                        probability = rand() % 100;  // probability of occurrence for each bacterium
                        if (probability <= 5 && c < N && d + 1 < N){  // if it is less than 5% and if the coordinates do not go beyond the field
                            if (N_N[c][d + 1] == 0)  // if the cell is empty
                                N_N[c][d + 1] = 1;  // birth of bacteria
                        }
                        probability = rand() % 100;
                        if (probability <= 5 && c - 1 >= 0 && d + 1 < N) {
                            if (N_N[c - 1][d + 1] == 0)
                                N_N[c - 1][d + 1] = 1;
                        }
                        probability = rand() % 100;
                        if (probability <= 5 && c - 1 >= 0 && d < N) {
                            if (N_N[c - 1][d] == 0)
                                N_N[c - 1][d] = 1;
                        }
                        probability = rand() % 100;
                        if (probability <= 5 && c - 1 >= 0 && d - 1 >= 0) {
                            if (N_N[c - 1][d - 1] == 0)
                                N_N[c - 1][d - 1] = 1;
                        }
                        probability = rand() % 100;
                        if (probability <= 5 && c < N && d - 1 >= 0) {
                            if (N_N[c][d - 1] == 0)
                                N_N[c][d - 1] = 1;
                        }
                        probability = rand() % 100;
                        if (probability <= 5 && c + 1 < N && d - 1 >= 0) {
                            if (N_N[c + 1][d - 1] == 0)
                                N_N[c + 1][d - 1] = 1;
                        }
                        probability = rand() % 100;
                        if (probability <= 5 && c + 1 < N && d < N) {
                            if (N_N[c + 1][d] == 0)
                                N_N[c + 1][d] = 1;
                        }
                        probability = rand() % 100;
                        if (probability <= 5 && c + 1 < N && d + 1 < N) {
                            if (N_N[c + 1][d + 1] == 0)
                                N_N[c + 1][d + 1] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        // output on display
        for (int e = 0; e < N; e++) {  
            for (int f = 0; f < N; f++) {
                if (N_N[e][f] == 0)
                    cout << " " << " ";
                if (N_N[e][f] != 0)
                    cout << N_N[e][f] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        
        //this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        
        /*auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        while (chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count() < delayInSeconds) {}*/

        /*if (i < D - 1)
            system("cls");*/
    }  

    return 0;

}


"GPT chat can't solve my problem" - obviously. It can write a 1st year university philosophy essay, not a C++ code.

Take a few steps back, and remove all of the code except the vector definition and output. Do you get a bunch of newlines output then? Change the vector definition to use 1 instead of 0, do you get a lot of 1 output then? That means the output is working, and the error is somewhere else in your code. Add back that code in very small parts, until it stops working. Then you should get an idea about when and where the problem might be.

https://godbolt.org/z/f88Pnboh9 - it displays something, and doesn't crash. Can you clarify your question?

whats the code supposed to do? What does it do instead? Pretend we know nothing about your task, because chances are high we really don't

@pptaszni i also had to read it twice, but OP actually states that it stops without crashing, and that there is no "output code" (i suppose they refer to exit code which in case of sefault or similar would be different from 0 and indicated on the console), but they dont claim there would be no output at all. Though I agree question should be clarified

I'm working in Visual Studio and outputting a vector to the console after each iteration of the main loop. At first the vector is output and everything works as it should, but then the program just stops. It doesn't give me any error code as it usually does. However, the main loop is not completed.

My code is supposed to simulate a small colony of bacteria that can reproduce and die. The simulation takes place over a certain number of days D. The main cycle removes these bacteria after each day. The numbers that fill the vector are the number of days lived by the bacterium.

please [edit] the question to clarify. Comments are only for comments, while all necessary information should be in the question

"Stops" as in nothing more happens but the program doesn't exit (indication of an infinite or long-running loop or something similar)? Or "stops" as in program exits when it shouldn't? Please ][edit] your question to give us more details.

And have you tried to run the program through a debugger? It doesn't catch a crash? How about using the debugger to step through the code line by line to see what happens?

"adding k bacteria" will loop forever if there are fewer than k empty positions

bool added = false;
do {  // iterate over coordinates until all bacteria can be inserted
    x = rand() % N;
    y = rand() % N;
    if (N_N[x][y] == 0) {
        N_N[x][y] = 1;
        added     = true;
    }
} while (!added);

What will happen if for every x and y your N_N[x][y] != 0 ? You got an infinite loop here.

@Banicsidy even if there is 1 free place that loop is very inefficient when N becomes large. You might roll random number very often with many repetitions befoer you find that 1 free spot. Rather than rolling a number in every iteration you can use a vector with indices from 0....N-1 and random shuffle it. Then iterate it from begin till end. Either you find a position or you dont, in which case you know there is none. This isnt optimal still (eg very poor memory locality) but much better than what you currently have
